# Why are my buttons shifted to the top of the screen?

Tags: listview, button, swiftui, ios-simulator

I am pretty new to coding and I am working on creating a settings tab for my user profile and am running into some bugs when running the simulator. Currently when I preview the view on the console, everything appears to be aligned correctly. However when I run the app in the simulator, the buttons get shifted up to the top of the screen, causing the view to be a dead end and nothing is clickable. The `navigationbartitle` is aligned in the correct spot, but the buttons themselves are shifted upwards. Heres my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = SettingsViewModel()
    @Binding var showSignInView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Log out") {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try viewModel.signOut()
                        showSignInView = true
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }         
            Button(role: .destructive) {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.deleteAccount()
                        showSignInView = true
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Delete Account")
            }          
            if viewModel.authProviders.contains(.email) {
                emailSection
            }
            if viewModel.authUser?.isAnonymous == true {
                anonymousSection
            }           
        }        
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.loadAuthProviders()
                    viewModel.loadAuthUser()                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
        }   
}    
    struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                SettingsView(showSignInView: .constant(false))
            }
        }
    }
```

iPhone simulator:

[image: Simulation view]

Xcode Preview:

[image: Console view]

I tried adding `.padding(.top, 100.0)` to push the buttons back down, but running into some issues with that. If I leave it at 100.0 the buttons push down and everything works the way it is supposed to. Obviously 100.0 is extreme and way too much. So I tried playing with the number to align it properly. But anything between 20.0-99.0, the app doesn't even allow me to click the setting button on the previous screen to see what it looks like. I'm at a lost for what I am doing wrong. Anyone have any suggestions?

Simulator view with .padding added:

[image: Simulation view with .padding added]

Updated view with recommended code changes:

[image: Updated view with recommended code changes]

UPDATE: Adding Profile view Code

Profile view code:

[image: Profile view code]

Comment: Try using `VStack {}` instead of `List`, and a `Spacer()` after the second `Button`

Answer (score 1):

You have a `NavigationStack` in your preview provider code, but not in contentView. This may cause the code to behave unexpectedly when not run in a preview, since you are using a `navigationBarTitle`.
Update your SettingsView by wrapping a `NavigationStack` around everything else.

Also, update your preview code to this:

```
struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       //removed the NavigationStack and put it in SettingsView
            SettingsView(showSignInView: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

Full code (with edits due to external references):

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Button("Log out") {
                    Task {
                        do {
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(role: .destructive) {
                    Task { do {
                    } catch {
                    }
                    }
                    } label: {
                        Text("Delete Account")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
            }
        }
    }
```

Tested on iPhone simulator iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.4:

[image]

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Looks like I am still getting the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: The code is working for me, I have added the full code that I used and the results I got to my answer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting, that still doesn't do it for me. Appreciate the help though!

Comment: That's strange... If you have added padding to your original code, try removing that.  When I put // rest of code in my full code, I was referring to the code that you had before you added .padding(.top, 100.0) Let me know if this does anything.

Comment: No, I don't have the padding anymore in the code. I've updated my original post to include a picture of my code after adding the NavigationStack like you mentioned.

Comment: That's very strange. I updated my answer with the exact code I used, with some parts removed due to external references. I got the desired result. Maybe try restarting Xcode or something?

Comment: I've done that and even erased all content and settings on the simulator device and still nothing. It worked fine when I would login and send the app straight to the settings view, but ever since I changed it to login  and go to the profile view then to via button go to the settings view, it bugged out. Could it be something in the profile view thats bugging it out?

Comment: Can you show me what code is in the profile view?

Comment: Also try setting Binding var showSignInView: Bool into Binding var showSignInView = false and removing showSignInView: .constant(false) in your previewProvider.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the profile view code.

Comment: Even with that code, it is a little difficult to debug it because of the variables that are missing, and possibly other structs. When I try directly using your code, many errors are popping up, so I have to edit it. When I do, it seems to work correctly. Can you tell me about SettingsViewModel()?